# I'm having trouble to scroll a page using capybara

Tags: ruby, web, automated-tests, capybara

I've tried to scroll a page using:

```
page.execute_script "window.scrollBy(0,10000)"
```

But the page simply doesn't scroll.
The url i'm trying to scroll is https://next.me/propostas

Can anyone help me? I'm newer to Ruby and Capybara, thanks

Comment: Yeah, that page messes with the scrolling. You won't be able to scroll it that way. Try emitting scroll wheel events, maybe it'll respond to those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried `"window.WheelEvent(0,1000)"` but it returns the message _unknown error: Failed to construct 'WheelEvent': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function._

Did I write right? 'Cause I didn't find any example for scroll wheel in Ruby

Comment: @WilsonAugusto What driver are you using?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, I'm using Selenium with Capybara and Cucumber

Comment: To use WheelEvents you'd need to create a wheel event and then dispatch it at the correct element on the page - something like `var evt = new WheelEvent('wheel', {deltaY: ??, wheelDeltaY: ??}); element.dispatchEvent(evt);`  I'm not sure what those values should be though or which element you need to dispatch them to for the page your using, you should be able to monitor events in Chrome and see what it normally sends. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

Comment: I was not able to scroll with Chrome, so I used safaridriver and it worked, I do not know why, I'm using the 2.33.506106 version of chromedriver, but thanks to everyone who helped me